# Can someone explain how date("YW", strtotime("2016-01-02")); returns “201653”?

Tags: php, date, week-number

```
date("YW", strtotime("2016-01-02")); returns “201653”
```

Year is OK
Week is from 2015

Comment: Look into ISO years. Jan 1 does *not* mean a new year. `echo date("oW", strtotime("2016-01-02"));`

Comment: Jan 1, is not exactly a new year. `:)`

Comment: Week 01 is the week with the year's first Thursday in it, according to the ISO definition;

Answer (score 3):

PHP is [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) compliant with dates:

> The purpose of this standard is to provide an unambiguous and well-defined method of representing dates and times, so as to avoid misinterpretation of numeric representations of dates and times, particularly when data are transferred between countries with different conventions for writing numeric dates and times.

This means the first week of the year is defined as:

> the week with the year's first Thursday in it
>
> If 1 January is on a Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday or Thursday, it is in week 01. If 1 January is on a Friday, Saturday or Sunday, it is in week 52 or 53 of the previous year (there is no week 00).

This means January 2nd of 2016 is *not* in week one of 2016 as far as PHP is concerned.

If you use the `o` flag for `date()` you will get the ISO-8601 year which wilol return 2015:

```
echo date("oW", strtotime("2016-01-02"));
// outputs: 201553
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/513754)

One way you may want to consider is checking if the month is January and the week number is 53 then it is the first week of the new calendar year (not ISO-8601 year).

```
if (date('n') == 1 && date('W') == 53) {
    // first calendar week of the year
}
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/513755)

Answer (score 1):

PHP is using the ISO-8601 specification for week numbers.

Definition of the first week of the year (ISO 8601):

> **There are mutually equivalent descriptions of week 01:**
>
> - the week with the year's first Thursday in it (the formal ISO definition),
> - the week with 4 January in it,
> - the first week with the majority (four or more) of its days in the starting year, and
> - the week starting with the Monday in the period 29 December – 4 January.
>
> If 1 January is on a Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday or Thursday, it is in week 01.
>   If 1 January is on a Friday, Saturday or Sunday, it is in week 52 or 53 of the previous year (there is no week 00). 28 December is always in the last week of its year.
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates

**Here a example:**

```
echo date("YW", strtotime("2016-01-02")); //201653
echo date("YW", strtotime("2016-01-04")); //201601
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP uses ISO-8601 week number of year, weeks starting on Monday.  If January 1st of a year is not on a Monday, that particular week is deemed to be the final week of the previous year; week 53.

Because January 1st 2016 was a Friday, it is part of the week commencing December 28th 2015.  If you run the code `echo date('Y-W', strtotime('2015-12-31'));` you will get the output '2015-53', so the days of the same week will also be week 53 according to ISO-8601.